# UITextField in UIToolBar not adhereing to Size Classes

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, size-classes

I have a UITextfield in a UIToolbar and it doesn't seem to want to stretch from end to end like it does on an iphone. So this is what I have for the w:any h:any size class

[image]

That works just fine on iphone devices. But when I align it on the w:regular h:regular size class for ipad it completely ignores it on the device.

[image]

In the preview it looks fine but once it is on a device (ipad) the UITextfield is tiny, its as wide as the one on an iphone.

Comment: Some more details would be good to get an idea of how exactly you've set this up. Are your constraints set to specific numbers, or are they set using multipliers and ratios?

Comment: I have the UIToolBar pinned to the view, leading, trailing and bottom. Same thing with the TableView above it, its pinned to the top layout guide, leading, trailing and the bottom is pinned to the top of the UIToolBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the information you provided in your comment, it sounds like you've set the constraints to a set number. I would suggest setting your constraints up using ratios and multipliers. This will make sure the constrained objects are based on the SuperView's size (or rather a percentage of it).

Check out the following links for more information:

- [This SketchyTech Tutorial](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2015/06/fear-and-loathing-in-auto-layout_29.html)
- [This Make App Pie Tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/11/25/proportional-sizes-in-autolayout/)
- [This Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: ah, thats right. You have lead me down the right path. Didn't think of it like that. Between the constraints and flexible space items something is getting screwed up.